# How is implemented Google's neural network for image recognition?

Tags: neural-network, deep-learning, image-recognition

I have a memoir to write and the main topic is comparing Google's deep learning algorithms for image recognition with the one that my teacher has made + create my own (based on the one that my teacher made) with incremental neural network and make a benchmark.

Can anyone give me some resources where I can learn more about the implementation of Google's deep learning neural network for image recognition ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Going Deeper With Convolution (or everything you need to know GoogLeNet if you know how a CNN works and is built) : http://www.cv-foundation.org/openaccess/content_cvpr_2015/papers/Szegedy_Going_Deeper_With_2015_CVPR_paper.pdf

Rethinking the Inception Architecture for Computer Vision (improvements) : https://arxiv.org/pdf/1512.00567.pdf

Hope it helps